# A continuous, increasing function with particular scaling and integral properties

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, monotone-functions

I would like to obtain an explicit description of a  continuous, non-decreasing function $f:[0,1]\to [0,\infty )$  with the following properties: (i)  $f(0)=0$; (ii) $\int_{0^+} f(x)/x\  dx=\infty$  and (iii) $\liminf_{x\to 0}f(x^2)/f(x)=0$.

The function $f(x)=-1/\ln(x)$ (near zero) initially looks like a good candidate, but fails to satisfy (iii).

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Original answer:**

There are many such functions; one example is $f(x) = \frac{x}{1-x}$ on $[0, 1)$ -- it is not hard to verify that all three properties hold.

Some motivation: I chose $x$ for the fast decay near $x = 0$, and $\frac{1}{1-x}$ to give a divergent integral around $x = 1$.

**Answer to updated question:**

Reframe the problem using the substitution $x = e^{-u}$, and define $g(u) = f(e^{-u})$, so our condition on $g : (a, \infty) \to [0, \infty)$ is that it is continuous and nonincreasing with $\lim_{u \to \infty} g(u) = 0$, $\int_b^\infty g(u) \,du = \infty$ for all $b \geq a$, and 
$$\liminf_{u \to \infty} \frac{g(2u)}{g(u)} = 0.$$
It is not hard to prove that if we strengthen the third condition to $\lim_{u \to \infty} \frac{g(2u)}{g(u)} = 0$, then no such function exists, which suggests that $g$ must have arbitrarily "steep" decreases over some intervals of the form $[u, 2u]$, while overall not decreasing too fast.

For the moment, let's relax the continuity requirement. Then we can try a function of the form 
$$g(u) = \frac{1}{h(\lfloor h^{-1}(u) \rfloor)}$$
for a very fast-growing positive function $h$, e.g. $h(u) = e^{u^2}$ (here $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ denotes the floor function). Intuitively, this function behaves asymptotically like $\frac{1}{u}$, and for $u$ with 
$$h(n) < u < h(n+1) < 2u < h(n+2),$$ 
we have 
$$\frac{g(2u)}{g(u)} = \frac{h(n)}{h(n+1)}$$
which goes to zero as $n \to \infty$, satisfying the second condition.

To check the integral condition, note that
$$\int_{h(k)}^\infty g(u) \,du = \sum_{n=k}^\infty \int_{h(n)}^{h(n+1)} g(u) \,du = \sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{h(n+1) - h(n)}{h(n)} = \infty.$$

Thus this choice of $g$ satisfies all of our requirements except continuity. To make it continuous, we can simply redefine it in a small neighborhood of each discontinuity at $u = h(n)$, so that instead of jumping from $h(n-1)$ to $h(n)$, it undergoes a very rapid linear decrease in that neighborhood. This can then be translated into a function $f$ which satisfies all of the original requirements via $f(x) = g(-\ln x)$.

Unfortunately, this might not be as explicit as you want -- it could be made more explicit if you can find an explicit continuous function which increasingly closely approximates the floor function.

Comment: If you instead wanted $f$ with a divergent integral near $x = 0$, i.e. the stronger condition that $\int_0^\delta f(x)/x \,dx = \infty$ for each $\delta > 0$, such functions also exist, but all examples I've found are much more complicated (since they must satisfy $\liminf_{x \to 0} f(x^2)/f(x) = 0$ but $\limsup_{x \to 0} f(x^2)/f(x) \neq 0$).

Comment: Yes, I wanted a divergent integral near zero - I have amended the question now (my mistake). So please do share your more complicated example(s).

Comment: Surprisingly the answer is yes (for any $p > 1$). Let $f$ be our (unsmoothed) function constructed as above, and note the function $f_p(x) = x^p f(x)$ is such that there are decreasing sequences of positive numbers $x_1, x_2, \dots$ and $c_1, c_2, \dots$ both converging to $0$ such that $f_p(x) = c_n x^p$ on $(x_{n+1}, x_n]$. So long as $x_n > \frac{p}{p-1}x_{n+1}$ (which is true for all $x_n$ for $n$ large enough), we can smooth $f_p$ near $x_{n+1}$ as follows: there is a line tangent to $f_p$ at some point $(x_n', c_n(x_n')^p)$ (for $x_n'$ with $x_{n+1} < x_n' \leq \frac{p}{p-1}x_{n+1}$)...

Comment: ...which passes through $(x_{n+1}, c_{n+1}x_{n+1}^p)$, i.e. the lower limit at $x_{n+1}$. If we redefine $f_p$ to be equal to this line on the segment $[x_{n+1}, x_n']$ for each $n$, and call the resulting function $f_p^*$, then it is not hard to see that $f_p^*$ is decreasing, continuous, and convex. With a little more work, the resulting smoothing $f^*$ of $f$ given by $f^*(x) = f_p^*(x)/x^p$ satisfies all of the desired properties (sufficiently close to $0$).

Comment: That $is$ surprising! I've tried to fill in the details and will outline these in a sequence of posts, to see if you concur.  In all that follows below I will take $h(u)=e^{u^2}$ and $g$ as in your original answer, with $x=e^{-u}$. Further, set $u_n=h(n)$ and $x_n= e^{-u_n}.$

Firstly, just a  pedantic query: presumably you meant to write ``$f_p^\ast$ is {\it non}-decreasing'' in the penultimate sentence?

Comment: Right, sorry — the intended word was “increasing”.

Comment: I agree with all of this; for 3, yes, $f_p^*$ should be Lipschitz continous, though for 4, I think $g^*$ will not be affine on the intervals $(\ln(1/x_n’), u_{n+1})$.

Comment: Note that $b_n = pc_n(x_n')^{p-1}$ and $a_n = (p-1)c_n (x_n')^p$, hence on the interval $(x_{n+1}, x_n')$, (after expanding and simplifying), we get $(f^*)'(x) = p(p-1)c_n(x_n')^{p-1}x^{-p-1}(x_n' - x) > 0$.